# Hive on spark. Reading parquet file

Tags: hadoop, hive, avro, parquet, spark-avro

I'm trying to read parquet file into Hive on Spark.

So I've found out that I should do something kind of that:

```
CREATE TABLE avro_test ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe' STORED 
AS AVRO TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='/files/events/avro_events_scheme.avsc'); 

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE parquet_test LIKE avro_test STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION '/files/events/parquet_events/';
```

where my avro scheme is:

```
{
 "type" : "parquet_file",
    "namespace" : "events",
    "name" : "events",
    "fields" : [
            { "name" : "category" , "type" : "string" },
            { "name" : "duration" , "type" : "long" },
            { "name" : "name" , "type" : "string" },
            { "name" : "user_id" , "type" : "string"},
            { "name" : "value" , "type" : "long" }
    ]
 }
```

As result I receive an error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
Operation not allowed: ROW FORMAT SERDE is incompatible with format 'avro', 
which also specifies a serde(line 1, pos 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I think we have to add inputforamt and outputformat classes. 

CREATE TABLE parquet_test
ROW FORMAT SERDE
   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT  
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'avro.schema.url''avro.schema.url'='/hadoop/avro_events_scheme.avsc');

I hope above would work.
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped but now for a line : `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE parquet_test LIKE avro_test STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION '/dir_to_file/file_name.parq/';` it returns error : `SQL Error: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input 'LIKE' expecting {<EOF>, '(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'AS',...` Could you please help with it as well?

Comment: you can refer this link.. https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/5833/create-hive-table-to-read-parquet-files-from-parqu.html                                                                   set PARQUET LOCATION '/dir_to_file' ,please exclude file_name.parq.

Comment: Indeed I don't need *.parq file in my directory, however it returns the same error saying that Hive fails on `LIKE` .

Comment: Is it possible that query returns error, because of the error made on previous steps?